# PySpark: Translating MSSQL Code w/Inner Joins, Case Statements, and Where Statements

Tags: sql-server, join, filter, pyspark, where-clause

I'm trying to replicate code that I wrote in MSSQL and translate it to PySpark.  I'm a noob at PySpark.

The query contains inner joins, embedded case when statements and a bunch of where statements for filtering.

```
SELECT        Table1.Part, Table1.Serial, Table1.AIRCRAFT_NUMBER, Table1.date_removed,
                         Table2.dbo.E15.TIME, Table2.dbo.E15.TSO, data.dbo.EE18.Allowable_Time,
                         CASE WHEN (data.dbo.EE18.Allowable_Time > 0)
                         THEN data.dbo.EE18.Allowable_Time - Table2.dbo.E15.TSO END AS CAL
FROM            Table1 INNER JOIN
                         Table2.dbo.E15 ON Table1.SEQ_ID = Table2.dbo.E15.SEQ_ID AND
                         Table1.Part = Table2.dbo.E15.Part AND
                         Table1.Serial = Table2.dbo.E15.Serial AND
                         Table1.DATE_REMOVED_DESCENDING = Table2.dbo.E15.DATE_REMOVED_DESCENDING INNER JOIN
                         data.dbo.EE18 ON Table2.dbo.E15.Part = data.dbo.EE18.PART_NUMBER AND
                         Table2.dbo.E15.TIME = data.dbo.EE18.TIME
WHERE        (Table1.Part LIKE '18%') AND (Table2.dbo.E15.TIME = 'I') AND
                         (data.dbo.EE18.Allowable_Time > 0) AND (Table2.dbo.E15.TSO <= 2) OR
                         (Table1.Part LIKE '18%') AND (Table2.dbo.E15.TIME = 'T') AND
                         (data.dbo.EE18.Allowable_Time > 0) AND (Table2.dbo.E15.TSO <= 20) OR
                         (Table1.Part LIKE '18%') AND (Table2.dbo.E15.TIME = 'L') AND
                         (data.dbo.EE18.Allowable_Time > 0) AND (Table2.dbo.E15.TSO <= 8)
ORDER BY Table1.date_removed DESC
```

What does the above query look like in PySpark code?  Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why not use a stored procedure? Then you don't have to worry about any kind of oddball dialect for the programming language you are using. I would closely at those where predicates. You seem to have mountains of unnecessary parenthesis and missing the important ones.

Comment: I don't know how to do stored procedures

Comment: Might be a good time to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to your question but is demonstrating how much cleaner your queries can look with some formatting. I also reworked the where predicates a little bit to avoid redundancy and fixed the logical problems with your parenthesis.

```
SELECT Table1.Part
    , Table1.Serial
    , Table1.AIRCRAFT_NUMBER
    , Table1.date_removed
    , Table2.dbo.E15.TIME
    , Table2.dbo.E15.TSO
    , data.dbo.EE18.Allowable_Time
    , CASE WHEN (data.dbo.EE18.Allowable_Time > 0) THEN data.dbo.EE18.Allowable_Time - Table2.dbo.E15.TSO END AS CAL
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2.dbo.E15 ON Table1.SEQ_ID = Table2.dbo.E15.SEQ_ID 
                        AND Table1.Part = Table2.dbo.E15.Part 
                        AND Table1.Serial = Table2.dbo.E15.Serial 
                        AND Table1.DATE_REMOVED_DESCENDING = Table2.dbo.E15.DATE_REMOVED_DESCENDING 
INNER JOIN data.dbo.EE18 ON Table2.dbo.E15.Part = data.dbo.EE18.PART_NUMBER 
                        AND Table2.dbo.E15.TIME = data.dbo.EE18.TIME
WHERE Table1.Part LIKE '18%' 
    AND data.dbo.EE18.Allowable_Time > 0 
    AND
    (
        Table2.dbo.E15.TIME = 'I' 
        AND 
        Table2.dbo.E15.TSO <= 2
    )
    OR
    (
        Table2.dbo.E15.TIME = 'T'
        AND
        Table2.dbo.E15.TSO <= 20
    )
    OR
    (
        Table2.dbo.E15.TIME = 'L'
        AND
        Table2.dbo.E15.TSO <= 8
    )
ORDER BY Table1.date_removed DESC
```